# Java query: Thread Syncronization issue

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using the below code to achieve synchronization in threads

```
package pkg.com.thread1;

public class Demo4 {

/**
 * @param args
 */

private static int count = 1;

public synchronized static void increment()
{
    count++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                increment();
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                increment();
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

 t1.start();
 t2.start();

 try {
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Count is : "+count);    

}

}
```

Still every time I am running the code, I am getting a different output. 
Can anyone please help with this? Am I missing something?

Comment: I consistently get 20001, and this is what I would expect. What other answers are you getting? Are you sure this is actually the version of the code you are running?

Comment: I ran it multiple times and I am always getting 20001

Comment: are you running the 'Demo4' or any other class containing main method, please check as the above program gives output as 2001 and as said it is what is expected.

Comment: Not reproducible.

Comment: also, I would recommend to not use "synchronization". Try using an AtomicInteger variable for better performance.

Comment: What hardware are you running this code on? What sort of outputs are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Synchronized method over Count variable declare the count variable as Atomic Integer like below.`private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();`. It will solve your problem. And don't forget to include `import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;`